# Accurately Convert from Straight Alpha to Premultiplied Alpha and Back

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I have an RGBA source image that I need to convert to Pre-Multiplied BGRA for use in WPF image display and scaling.  Afterwards I need to convert the PBGRA back into straight RGBA.  I've been using these formulae to convert and convert back:

```
PC = C * A / 255.0 + 0.5
```

and back:

```
C = 255.0 * PC / A + 0.5
```

where `C` is Color and `PC` is Pre-Multiplied Color and both are of type `byte`.

The problem is that this is producing a lot of off-by-one errors when I do nothing but convert the RGBA to PBGRA and back to RGBA with no further processing and then comparing the original RGBA with the resulting converted RGBA.

Is there a convert-to and convert-back set of algorithms that will produce an exact copy of the original image?

I am working with C# but any examples with C/C++ or Java would work.

This is the code I use to pre-multiply:

```
Func<byte, byte, byte> preMultiply = (source, alpha) => (byte)(source * (double)alpha / 255.0 + 0.5);
```

And to convert back:

```
Func<byte, byte, byte> deMultiply = (color, alpha) => {
    if (alpha == 0) return color;

    return (byte)(255.0 * color / alpha + 0.5);
};
```

Is there any way to do that is "less" lossy?

Comment: Your issue is probably to do with rounding and decimal precision. Can you give an example of an input for which you're not getting the output you expect along with the actually expected output.

Comment: Why don't you use [`PixelFormats.Bgra32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.bgra32(v=vs.110).aspx), without pre-multiplied channels?

Comment: Why this unexplained downvote ?

Comment: @Clemens I did try that, but some of the processing of the image I have planned requires Pbgra32 and won't work with anything else.

Comment: Ok, but the answer to your question "is there a convert-to and convert-back set of algorithms that will produce an exact copy of the original image?" is a definite "No, there isn't", because (as explained in the answer) you may lose all original color channel information during convert-to. The only way to handle this is to keep a copy of the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not, this conversion generates irreversible information loss.

To understand why, let A=128. Then all C values in the range [0,255] will map to [0,127]. Obviously, one bit is lost forever.

With A=0, you lose... all the bits.